# Basic UDP Client/Server won't work?

Tags: c, sockets

I am hoping that this is a relatively simple answer to my question. I am attempting to learn how to program in sockets and I just can't seem to get a basic UDP example working. I am attempting to just send a string "hello" from one computer to another read it on the screen.

I started with this website
https://www.programminglogic.com/sockets-programming-in-c-using-udp-datagrams/

then tried:
https://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html

I have also looked at
https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html

but it seems that each time I try to code nothing happens. I get no errors, I just don't get any communication. I can ping my server computer from my client computer at least

My setup: 
I currently have two computers one running Ubuntu 16.04 the other 14.04.
I was hoping to start off with something easy by connecting them directly. But I have tried connecting them through a switch. No success.

On the "server" computer I set up my network card to have by opening the terminal and

```
sudo ifconfig enps60 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To create my server code in terminal I type

```
gedit udp_server.c
```

and in the text editor I type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int udpSocket, nBytes;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, cientAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;


    /* Create UDP socket */
    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /* Configure settings in address struct */
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(0);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

    /* Bind Socket */
    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    printf("bind complete. Port number = %d\n", ntohs(serverAddr.sin_port));

    addr_size = sizeof(serverStorage);

    while(1)
    {
        nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)%clientAddr, &addr_size);
        printf("any bytes: %d\n, nBytes);
    }

}
```

I then compile my code in terminal by typing
gcc -o udp_server udp_server.c

On my client computer (ubuntu 14.04) I open the terminal and type

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then to create my client code in terminal I type

```
gedit udp_client.c
```

and in the text editor I type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int udpSocket, portNum, nBytes;
    char buffer[1024] = "hello";
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    unsigned int alen;

    /*create UDP socket */
    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 

    /* Configure settings in address struct */
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(0);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

    addr_size = sizeof(serverAddr);

    while(1)
    {
         printf("sending %s\n", buffer);
         nBytes = strlen(buffer);
         sendto(udpSocket, buffer, nBytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, addr_size);
         sleep(1);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I apologize if my code isn't that polished also.

Comment: Can you ping one machine from the other?

Comment: Add error check code (that is, check that the sendto produces a positive value, and if it doesn't then check what errno holds. Same with the recvfrom, print what errno holds if the return is -1 (assuming the recvfrom completes at all).

Comment: UDP can be surprisingly hard to get working.  I suggest using two copies of netcat (that is, one on each machine) to ensure that you can send and receive UDP packets.  Once that's working, try using your sender to a netcat receiver, and then netcat sending to your receiver.  Finally, try your own sender/receiver pair.

Comment: I'll bet anything the firewall is blocking it.

Comment: ... or a DHCP service is changing those IP addresses..

Comment: In your home network, what is the IP Address of your network???  In most home networks, 192.168.1.1 would be a router address... which is an address you are using in your server code.

Comment: Steve, yes I can ping one machine from another.

Comment: Does using port 0 on both sides make sense? It triggers the use of a  random port, doesn't it. The chances client and server bind to the same port is quite low, I'd say. Or am I missing something? Did you try something different from 0, for example 65432?

Comment: Steve, I have added some error coding to my client program and I get a return value of -1 on the sendto? I don't know how to use errno to tell me what this means though.

Comment: Don't add "some" error checking.  Check *every* call.  You won't get any errors unless you write code that prints error messages.

Comment: If `sendto` returns 0, it will set `errno`.  You can print a message with `perror` or query it with `strerror`

Comment: Thanks William but I am not good at writing code, what do I write in c?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well thanks guys for all the suggestions, but I do have some code that works.

I still am very unsure how any of this works, but for starters I was selecting an incorrect port number. According to Steve Summitt I checked my connection using Netcat, and when I would look at port 0 netcat would kindly let me know that I can't choose a port number that low. This is a bit confusing as everything I am reading says that port numbers start at 0. Also there is a thing about trying not to use well known ports which used to be 0-255 but is now 0-1023. I was trying to figure out if I know what ports I can use or not and I came across this.

https://sort.veritas.com/public/documents/vie/7.3/aix/productguides/html/sfcfsha_config/apgs04s03.htm

Although I am unsure the context is only when using IPv6 protocol?

Also I found this list.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

I guess there are a bunch of applications on every machine that uses these ports?

**The quick solution:** I set the port to 1024 and forgot to bind my client socket to my client computers network card. I also changed the way I do memset (I thought I understood it, but I might not)

**for the complete solution:**

Current Setup:
I have two Ubuntu machines connected together by a simple switch. The machines are what I am calling a server (ubuntu 16.04) and a client (ubuntu 14.04).

The first step I did is assign static IPs to each machine (I think this is only recommended for my server computer, but I didn't know how to get my DHCP address of my client in c).

in my server computer I opened my terminal (ctrl + alt + t)

```
sudo ifconfig enp6s0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

in the client computer I opened my terminal and typed

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

now going back to the server computer in terminal I typed

```
gedit udp_server.c
```

which opened up a text editor

```
/************** UDP Server Code *****************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int udpSocket, nBytes;
    char buffer[5];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;
    int i;

    /* Create UDP socket */
    udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /* Configure settings in address struct */
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(1024);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero);

    /* Bind socket with address struct */
    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    printf("bind complete port number %d\n", ntohs(serverAddr.sin_port));

    /* Initialize size variable to be used later on */
    addr_size = sizeof(serverStorage);

    while(1)
    {
         nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket, buffer, 5, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &addr_size);
         printf("any bytes %d\n", nBytes);
    }

return 0;
}
```

now for the client code I typed (on my client computer)

```
gedit udp_client.c
```

which opened up a text editor

```
/************ UDP client code **********/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int udpSocket, portNum, nBytes;
     char buffer[1024] = "hello";
     struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
     socklen_t addr_size;
     unsigned int alen;

     /* Create UDP socket */
     udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

     /* Configure client settings in address struct */
     memset((char *)&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(clientAddr));
     clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
     clientAddr.sin_port = htons(0);

     if(bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr)) < 0)
     {
         perror("bind failed");
         return 0;
     }

     printf("client bound");

     /* configure server settings in struct */
     memset((char *)&serverAddr, '0', sizeof(serverAddr));
     serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serverAddr.sin_port = htons(1024);
     serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");

     printf("the socket ip addr is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr));

     addr_size = sizeof(serverAddr);

     while(1)
     {
          sleep(2);
          nBytes = strlen(buffer);

          if(sendto(udpSocket, buffer, nBytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1)
          {
                 perror("send to");
                 exit(1);
          }

          printf("sent %s\n", buffer);
     }

return 0;
}
```

some extra notes

- I actually don't know if I need to bind my sockets on my client side? I bound it to port 0 and everything worked peachey. I am thinking might run into issues if I try to receive from the server?
- I am still working on a metaphor for how to think about ports

  - I am going with that the IP address is the network card address (city) and the port number is the address within that city (task, application). Like many people can reside in a city, many tasks or programs can reside on a machine and each one might want to communicate to the world.
- This is only the most basic information (I don't cover other things like connect(), send(), write(), sendmsg() as I don't know how to use them)
- hopefully this post makes it easier on the next guy.